# What is the difference between 'kill' and the 'k' option within 'top' in Linux?

Tags: command-line, kill, top

I found out from http://www.tecmint.com/12-top-command-examples-in-linux/ (it's number 7 on that webpage) that you can use the `k` option to terminate a program. Would that work in the same way as quitting `top` and using `kill`?

Answer (score 2):

The command `kill` can be used to send a signal to a process. Useful signals, as in `man`, are: HUP, INT, KILL, STOP, CONT, and 0.

Example:

`sudo kill -9 1234` - send signal KILL to process with pid 1234

`top` can be used to watch Linux processes. There is an option on this command to send signals to processes too. You should already know process PID:

1. After starting `top`, find process you would like to send a signal.
2. Press <kbd>k</kbd>.
3. Inform for which PID you would like to send signal.
4. Inform which signal you want and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
5. Signal will be sent to process PID.

Want to know more about [Linux Signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same. They both need a PID and signal to send.

By  default they both send `SIGTERM` and you can pick another signal to send too.